# PHP - Не получается отправлять эл.почту

Tags: php, ubuntu

Пытаюсь отправить почту с сервера на PHP. в php.ini указал:

```
    sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Попробовал - ничего не получается. Сделал то же самое, но на другом сервере - почта отправлена, но письмо попадает в спам.
Вопрос следующий: что нужно настроить, чтобы почта отправлялась через PHP и не попадала в спам?
Пользуюсь Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: То что вы в `php.ini` указали путь, письмо не отправится ;) Нужно грамотно настроить почтовый сервис и все будет отправляться. А по поводу спама, скорей всего ничего не поделать, отправляют в спам, потому что у вас недоверенный источник (ваш ип).

Answer (score 0):

### Проблемы

- пользователь от имени которого отправляется почта должен совпадать с пользователем который авторизуется для отправки (smtp)
- вам может казаться, что всё хорошо, и письма к вам приходят (ну и что, что спам, персонально можно указать "доверяй"). Однако в один прекрасный момент вы поймете, что например mail.ru вообще не принимает вашу почту и т.д.
- в рамках борьбы со спамом провайдеры сильно ужесточили правила обработки почты

### Решения

Есть два основных подхода к решению данной задачи (создание собственного почтового сервера мы НЕ рассматриваем):

1. **использовать релейный хост** (smtp relay): почта будет перенаправляться/отправляться через другой сторонний сервис (yandex, google, mailgun)

   - [sSMTP](https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP)
   - Postfix + Stunnel
2. **использовать [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)**, используется многими CMS для отправки почты

> некоторые рекомендации:
>
> - используйте Яндекс Почта для домена (теперь это [connect](https://connect.yandex.ru)) и пароли приложений, если у вас есть свой домен
> - используйте псевдонимы почтового ящика для тонкой настройки
> - тестировали и работаем с postfix/stunnel, ssmtp показался медленным